# the nodejs and mongo db find

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use this code to connect to my mongo db localhost and find the "names" but i have a problem in consol.log:

```
url = require("url"),
emitter = require("events").EventEmitter,
assert = require("assert"),

mongo = require("mongodb"),
Cursor = mongo.Cursor;

var uristring = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test"; 
var mongoUrl = url.parse (uristring);


mongo.MongoClient.connect (uristring, function (err, db) { 
    var test = db.collection ("test")
        console.log ("Success connecting to " + mongoUrl.protocol + "//" + mongoUrl.hostname + ".");

        console.log (test.find({},{name:1,_id:0}));
    db.close();
});
```

when i use `db.test.find({},{name:1,_id:0})` in my terminal in mongo its returning `{ "name" : "pooya" }`
but in nodjs code it return:

```
Success connecting to mongodb://localhost.
{ db: 
   { domain: null,
     _events: {},
     _maxListeners: 10,
     databaseName: 'test',
     serverConfig: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _maxListeners: 10,
        _callBackStore: [Object],
        _commandsStore: [Object],
        auth: [Object],
        _dbStore: [Object],
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 27017,
        options: [Object],
        internalMaster: true,
        connected: true,
        poolSize: 5,
        disableDriverBSONSizeCheck: false,
        _used: true,
        replicasetInstance: null,
        emitOpen: false,
        ssl: false,
        sslValidate: false,
        sslCA: null,
        sslCert: undefined,
        sslKey: undefined,
        sslPass: undefined,
        serverCapabilities: [Object],
        name: 'localhost:27017',
        socketOptions: [Object],
        logger: [Object],
        eventHandlers: [Object],
        _serverState: 'connected',
        _state: [Object],
        recordQueryStats: false,
        socketTimeoutMS: [Getter/Setter],
        _readPreference: [Object],
        db: [Circular],
        dbInstances: [Object],
        connectionPool: [Object],
        isMasterDoc: [Object] },
     options: 
      { read_preference_tags: null,
        read_preference: 'primary',
        url: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test',
        native_parser: true,
        readPreference: [Object],
        safe: false,
        w: 1 },
     _applicationClosed: false,
     slaveOk: false,
     bufferMaxEntries: -1,
     native_parser: true,
     bsonLib: 
      { BSON: [Object],
        Long: [Object],
        ObjectID: [Object],
        DBRef: [Function: DBRef],
        Code: [Function: Code],
        Timestamp: [Object],
        Binary: [Object],
        Double: [Function: Double],
        MaxKey: [Function: MaxKey],
        MinKey: [Function: MinKey],
        Symbol: [Function: Symbol] },
     bson: { promoteLongs: true },
     bson_deserializer: 
      { Code: [Function: Code],
        Symbol: [Function: Symbol],
        BSON: [Object],
        DBRef: [Function: DBRef],
        Binary: [Object],
        ObjectID: [Object],
        Long: [Object],
        Timestamp: [Object],
        Double: [Function: Double],
        MinKey: [Function: MinKey],
        MaxKey: [Function: MaxKey],
        promoteLongs: true },
     bson_serializer: 
      { Code: [Function: Code],
        Symbol: [Function: Symbol],
        BSON: [Object],
        DBRef: [Function: DBRef],
        Binary: [Object],
        ObjectID: [Object],
        Long: [Object],
        Timestamp: [Object],
        Double: [Function: Double],
        MinKey: [Function: MinKey],
        MaxKey: [Function: MaxKey],
        promoteLongs: true },
     _state: 'connected',
     pkFactory: 
      { [Function: ObjectID]
        index: 2954887,
        createPk: [Function: createPk],
        createFromTime: [Function: createFromTime],
        createFromHexString: [Function: createFromHexString],
        isValid: [Function: isValid] },
     forceServerObjectId: false,
     safe: false,
     notReplied: {},
     isInitializing: true,
     openCalled: true,
     commands: [],
     logger: { error: [Function], log: [Function], debug: [Function] },
     tag: 1416152062206,
     eventHandlers: 
      { error: [],
        parseError: [],
        poolReady: [],
        message: [],
        close: [] },
     serializeFunctions: false,
     raw: false,
     recordQueryStats: false,
     retryMiliSeconds: 1000,
     numberOfRetries: 60,
     readPreference: { _type: 'ReadPreference', mode: 'primary', tags: undefined } },
  collection: 
   { db: 
      { domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _maxListeners: 10,
        databaseName: 'test',
        serverConfig: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        _applicationClosed: false,
        slaveOk: false,
        bufferMaxEntries: -1,
        native_parser: true,
        bsonLib: [Object],
        bson: [Object],
        bson_deserializer: [Object],
        bson_serializer: [Object],
        _state: 'connected',
        pkFactory: [Object],
        forceServerObjectId: false,
        safe: false,
        notReplied: {},
        isInitializing: true,
        openCalled: true,
        commands: [],
        logger: [Object],
        tag: 1416152062206,
        eventHandlers: [Object],
        serializeFunctions: false,
        raw: false,
        recordQueryStats: false,
        retryMiliSeconds: 1000,
        numberOfRetries: 60,
        readPreference: [Object] },
     collectionName: 'test',
     internalHint: null,
     opts: {},
     slaveOk: false,
     serializeFunctions: false,
     raw: false,
     readPreference: { _type: 'ReadPreference', mode: 'primary', tags: undefined },
     pkFactory: 
      { [Function: ObjectID]
        index: 2954887,
        createPk: [Function: createPk],
        createFromTime: [Function: createFromTime],
        createFromHexString: [Function: createFromHexString],
        isValid: [Function: isValid] },
     serverCapabilities: undefined },
  selector: {},
  fields: { name: 1, _id: 0 },
  skipValue: 0,
  limitValue: 0,
  sortValue: undefined,
  hint: null,
  explainValue: undefined,
  snapshot: undefined,
  timeout: true,
  tailable: undefined,
  awaitdata: undefined,
  oplogReplay: undefined,
  numberOfRetries: 5,
  currentNumberOfRetries: 5,
  batchSizeValue: 0,
  raw: false,
  readPreference: { _type: 'ReadPreference', mode: 'primary', tags: undefined },
  returnKey: undefined,
  maxScan: undefined,
  min: undefined,
  max: undefined,
  showDiskLoc: undefined,
  comment: undefined,
  tailableRetryInterval: 100,
  exhaust: false,
  partial: false,
  slaveOk: false,
  maxTimeMSValue: undefined,
  connection: undefined,
  totalNumberOfRecords: 0,
  items: [],
  cursorId: { _bsontype: 'Long', low_: 0, high_: 0 },
  dbName: undefined,
  state: 0,
  queryRun: false,
  getMoreTimer: false,
  collectionName: 'test.test' }
```

why its happening?how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

You are using the API wrongly. The MongoDB driver returns the query results asynchronously, via callback, not synchronously like in most languages you probably met so far, if you are new to node.js.

So, basically you are doing this

```
var results = test.find({},{name:1,_id:0})
console.log (results);
```

But what you really want to do is:

```
 test.find({name:1,_id:0}, new function(error, results)
  {
    if(error! = null) console.log(error);
    else //do whatever you want with the results
  });
```

Keep in mind that the code after `test.find()` will keep running independently of the query and its results. The results processing will be called when the query is finished.
Btw. I also think parameters passed to your `find()` method are somehow wrong. The query should be the first parameter, and in your example it's second, if I'm not mistaken. The method looks like this: `find(query[, options], callback)`.

You can find the documentation of the MongoDB driver [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html), including the `find` method.

You should more or less do the same with the `find()` method as you did with the `connect()` method in which callback you are writing the query.

If you are not comfortable with the notion of asynchronous, event driven or non-blocking programming please consider reading these links:

http://book.mixu.net/node/ch7.html

http://justinklemm.com/node-js-async-tutorial/

EDIT:

Sorry, I must edit myself. The callback has two parameters, the FIRST one is the error, the SECOND are the results. Haven't used this for a while.

Comment: so in non-blocking it look like something like that but it returns undefined:

mongo.MongoClient.connect (uristring, function (err, db) { 
     db.collection ("test", function (collection) {
     console.log ("Success connecting to " + mongoUrl.protocol + "//" + mongoUrl.hostname + ".");
  collection.find({},{name:1,_id:0}, function(results)
    {
   console.log(results);
   db.close();
    });
 });
});

Comment: As I said earlier, you are also using the `collection.find()` method wrong. It should be `collection.find({name:1,_id:0}, new function...)`. You are skipping the first paramater for no apparent reason. The second parameter are the query options such as `explain`, `limit`s, `timeout`, etc.
The first parameter of the callback is an error object which can report a fail in the query. So the callback can look like new function(error,results). You can check that error for more details.

Comment: Please check the answer again, I have made a mistake and corrected it now.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in test.find({},{name:1,_id:0}) query as first part is filter part and second part is projection part.